# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, vb.net, highcharts

am trying to add a highchart to my existing website, i have tested this on a new website and it has worked, however when i add this to my own existing one it gives me some errors:

the code is from the highchart.

my code error in bold:

```
   $(function() {

       $('#container').highcharts({
  *
```

> ***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'***

```
               chart: {
               type: 'column'
           },
           title: {
               text: 'Chart'
           },
           xAxis: {
           categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas']

           },
           yAxis: {
               title: {
                   text: 'KWH'
               }
           },

           series: [{

               name: 'June',
               color: '#92D050',
               data: [1, 0]
           },

             {
                 type: 'line',
                 color: '#FF0000',
                 name: 'May',
                 data: [0, 4]
}]           });

   });
```

also when i debug it says this on the console

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
> Dashboard.aspx:393 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no
> method 'draggable'
```

i have copied the code from the highchart like i did with the previous ones i made, however one thing i have notice for this site i have master page, so maybe it might be something there...

Comment: Are you loading the Highcharts library?

Comment: usually that means your code is executing before the library is loaded, make sure it is listed before this code and actually is loading in

Comment: How is related to PHP. ASP.NET, VB.NET or .NET?

Comment: Have you included or referenced highcharts lib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have some missing dependencies. Make sure you are referencing all required libraries.